# I want custom sorting order for attribute for each category magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, layered-navigation, sorting

I want custom sorting order for attributes for each category.
Please see attached image.
If in the category 1, the colour option displaying at the top, then for a category two size options would be the first. means I want custom sorting order.
Can you, guys, please let me know the exact file from where this sorting option working.

[image]